# Merge squid and squid3 tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Should we merge [squid3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/squid3) and [squid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/squid), and make [squid3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/squid3) an alias of [squid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/squid)?

Currently there's 74 questions tagged [squid3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/squid3), and 117 tagged [squid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/squid). Of those tagged squid, a large portion appears to be tagged squid3 as well, and some of those tagged only with squid appears to be about squid3 as well.

In short the volume is not large enough to warrant version-specific tags in my opinion, and the lifecycle of releases is long enough that I doubt there will be much of a problem with users confusing versions. Squid2 was depreceated in 2011...

In short - [squid3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/squid3) should be an alias of [squid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/squid)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've merged [squid3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/squid3) into [squid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/squid) and created a [squid3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/squid3)->[squid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/squid) synonym.

Any new question tagged with [squid3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/squid3) will be tagged with [squid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/squid) instead.